# How can an unconfirmed transaction be removed from the memory pool?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, unconfirmed-transactions, mempool, revert-transaction

Using Bitcoind and Json-RPC, how can I remove an unconfirmed transaction from the memory pool?

The scenario being that I want to remove the unconfirmed transaction because it's not getting confirmed, and it's preventing me from sending new transactions spending the same inputs because Bitcoind considers it a double spend.

Answer (score 6):

Try the [`removeprunedfunds`](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#removeprunedfunds) RPC command. It

> deletes the specified transaction from the wallet. … This will effect wallet balances.

Comment: don't know why you're voted down.. that did it for me

Comment: This is correct, but it should be noted that `removeprunedfunds` will remove the tx from just the local node's mempool and not necessarily from the mempool of other nodes that the tx may have propagated to.

Answer (score 1):

There is no RPC command available to remove objects from the mempool.

Comment: outdated reply, see @Geremia's answer

Comment: Not really. Removal from wallet and removal from mempool are two distinct operations.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a good way to clear just a single transaction from the mempool, but you can shutdown bitcoind and then delete ~/.bitcoin/mempool.dat and clear the entire mempool, and then restart bitcoind